# Inline Image and DIV and responsive

Tags: html, css, inline

I'm not a programmer and I've been trying to build this page as designed but I'm struggling to make it responsive.
For desktop I want to have an image on the left and a div on the right on the same line. However, on mobile i want then to be 100% and be on top of each other. And on top of this i want them wrapped in a div that the content is no more than 1000px.
Also, the div that i want to be aligned to the image, has an image inside and text as well.

This is how my CSS looks like:

```
.centerdiv{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin:auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.violet{
  background:#c3c1ea;
  z-index: 1;
  width:100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display:block;

}
.textondiv{
  padding: 0.5em 3em;
  font-family: 'Futura BT Light', 'Century Gothic';
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align:left;
}
.titleviolet {
  z-index: 3;
  margin:auto;
  width: 100%; 
  text-align: center;
}
```

And this is the HTML:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
  <img src="https:..." />
  <div class="violet">
    <div class="titleviolet"><img src="https:..."/>
      <div class="textondiv">bla bla bla bla</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

(also... I never worked with .js but I'm willing to figure out how to if it makes this easier)
I appreciate any help I could get, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If all of your target devices support it, you can easily have a layout with flexbox (http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

I slightly modified your code to utilize flex: http://codepen.io/davidkatona/pen/woXjxy

```
<div class="centerdiv">
  <img class="responsive-image" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
  <div class="violet">
    <div class="titleviolet">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
      <div class="textondiv">
        bla bla bla bla
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.centerdiv{
  width:100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  height:100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.responsive-image {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.violet{
  background:#c3c1ea;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  display:block;
  flex-grow: 1;
}


.textondiv{
  padding: 0.5em 3em;
  font-family: 'Futura BT Light', 'Century Gothic';
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align:left;
}

.titleviolet {
  z-index: 3;
  margin:auto;
  width: 100%; 
  text-align: center;
}
```

Please let me know if it suits your needs.

One additional tip: usually it's better to use semantic class names like ".main-content-container" instead of design-related like ".violet" because whenever you would like to change its background to let's say blue it won't be only a one-line change but you have to find and replace every occurrence of "violet" class in the html.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this...

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
  <img class="responsive-image" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
  <div class="violet">
    <div class="titleviolet"><img class="responsive-image" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
      <div class="textondiv">bla bla bla bla</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use display inline-flex on centerdiv for dextop view which you missed to add on your html. And also use img-responsive class for images . And most important is you need use media query css for mobile device to achieve the  mobile view. [LiveOnFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vtLcp0er/)

```css
body{
 margin:0;
 }
.img-responsive {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: auto;
}
.centerdiv {
 display:inline-flex;
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.violet {
  background: #c3c1ea;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}

.textondiv {
  padding: 0.5em 3em;
  font-family: 'Futura BT Light', 'Century Gothic';
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
}

.titleviolet {
  z-index: 3;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
@media only screen and (max-width:768px){
  .centerdiv{
    display:block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="centerdiv">
<img class="img-responsive" src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSipAOtp2qmDZB4Y7N8OE8nixMcnvKDAJvQJhdz1-aa3MX6-i1fcIDGSU-wow" />
  <div class="violet">
    <div class="titleviolet"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://choralista.pl/cfs/files/files/7pGEYN92YG8vyGcEJ/DemoStampRotate01-e1400242575670.png?token=eyJhdXRoVG9rZW4iOiIifQ%3D%3D" />
      <div class="textondiv">bla bla bla bla</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Mostafa! Thanks very much for you help, I'm starting to manage to put this together!! however.. is there a way to avoid the image from stretching? Thank you!